# Counterexample to a generalization of planar convex hulls

Tags: conformal-geometry, convex-hulls

I am looking for a counter example to the following conjecture:

- for every finite compact region $\mathcal{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ that is defined by a rectifiable Jordan curve
- and every fixed and finite pointset $\mathrm{P}\subset\mathcal{R}$
- and for every conformal mapping $f:\mathcal{R}\mapsto\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{R}$ to a compact convex region $\mathcal{C}$

**the set $\pmb{\lbrace\lbrace p_i,p_j\rbrace\,|\,\lbrace f(p_i),f(p_j)\rbrace\in CH(f(\mathrm{P}))\rbrace}$** of edges that constitute  to the convex hull $\mathrm{CH}(f(\mathrm{P}))$ of the image of $\mathrm{P}$ under the mapping $f$, that takes $\mathcal{R}$ to $\mathcal{C}$, **is the same**.

I assume the correctness of the conjecture because the construction of the convex hull of a set of points in the euclidean plane via Graham scan is based on extremal angles between edges and should thus be invariant under conformal mappings between convex regions, which in turn would imply that the convex region, to which a non-convex region  is initially mapped conformally, isn't signifant because we can always "reach" any other convex region by a composition with a single additional conformal mapping.

Comment: What is a "finite region"?? What is a "conformal map" between closed regions? Conformal on the boundary too?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko a finite region shall be one with finite upper bound on the distances between pairs of points. If makes a difference, then the answers can refer to the case of conformal only for inner points and conformal also for boundary points separately; I would be happy to learn about those differences.